# Understanding exceptions in a constructor (by the conversion C-string to long example)

Tags: c++

I myself is a Java-developer and now I'm trying to understand how to do it in the most efficient way in C++. After reading that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c/16575025#16575025) I decided to write the following:

```
//Headers omitted
class integer_validator
{
public:
    integer_validator(const char* const str);
    bool is_valid();
    long get_number();
private:
    bool valid;
    long result;
};

integer_validator::integer_validator(const char* const str)
{ 
    char *endptr;
    result = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);
    if(*endptr == '\0') valid = true;
    else valid = false;
}

bool integer_validator::is_valid()
{
    return valid;
}

long integer_validator::get_number()
{
    if(!valid)
        throw std::exception();
    return result;
}
int main ()
{
    integer_validator vv("123123");
    integer_validator v("123123a");
    std::cout << vv.get_number() << std::endl; //prints the number
    std::cout << v.get_number() << std::endl;  //throws the exception
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1953964f17efb690)**

And it works perfectly fine. But I'm not sure about some things I did. Is it considered good to put any piece of logic into a constructor? I actually do the validation within the constructor's body and I use only the C-functions.

So should I be afraid of throwing an exception during the construction in that case?

Comment: Why do you pass the string to the constructor? It looks weird and counter-intuitive. You would expect a validator objects to be able to check many strings.. well, at least I would...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath So what should I pass to then? I thought that it looks good because the purpose of that class is to validate if the string represent a number.

Comment: Nothing.......?

Comment: @St.Antario In case of integer validation you could pass some validation parameters, e.g. the limits of valid integer values: `integer_validator::integer_validator(int lower_bound, int upper_bound)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(*endptr == '\0') valid = true;
else valid = false;
```

would be better as just

```
valid = *endptr == '\0';
```

(or maybe even `valid = !*endptr;`, in the traditional C style).

Note that [this isn't a sufficient check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14176593/1763356).

Answer (score 2):

From the c++ specification's point of view a constructor is allowed to throw an exception (in opposite to destructor). So your code is fine.

On the other hand I don't see any advantage why it should be validated directly in the constructor. You could do it in is_valid method as well. Furthermore, if you moved the valifation code out from the constructor to a private method, you would gain an easy way to keep responsibility of handling low-level exceptions inside you class.
So, although your code is valid semantically, its design needs some improvement.

I hope I helped:)

Comment: "... c++ specification's point of view a constructor is allowed to throw an exception (in opposite to destructor)." For practical purposes, this is good advice to follow (don't throw from a destructor), but the C++ specification *does not* disallow throwing from a destructor. Throwing from a destructor is perfectly valid. It just doesn't have very safe or useful behavior since the program will terminate if an exception is thrown in a destructor while an exception is already propogating.